# Excel - Counting how many Strings in cell block

Tags: string, excel, function

I am trying to get the amount of a specific String in a cell block, and then place the number of how many times that String appears in the cell block.

Example:

```
A1:
Test
Test
Not a Test
Test
Not a Test
Test
Test
```

The function would return 5, because there are 5 "Test" out of the 7 inputs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CountIf should help you. your second argument would be the string you are looking for.

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I just solved it by testing out functions about 30 seconds ago.